# How To Raise Exception with Message in Ada

Tags: exception, ada

I'm struggling a little bit to raise exceptions the way I'm used to coming from a C# background.

I have a utility function that expects input values to be in a very specific range, as defined by an external standard. If a value is supplied outside of that range (and there is one value in the middle of the range that is also invalid), then I want to raise an exception to the caller so that they break.

From what I can tell, the syntax is `raise Invalid_Argument;`

But- is it possible to supply a message with the exception? e.g. the `Invalid_Argument` exception is somewhat self-explanatory, but I could see further detail specifying what was wrong with the argument. How do I write a brief error message to be stuck into the exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It used (Ada 95) to be you had to write

```
Ada.Exceptions.Raise_Exception (Invalid_Argument’Identity,
                                "message");
```

(see [Ada95RM 11.4.2](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95lrm/ARM_HTML/RM-11-4-2.html)(6)) but since Ada 2005 you’ve been able to say

```
raise Invalid_Argument with "message";
```

([A2005RM 11.3](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-11-3.html)).

Note that the string part is a string *expression*, so you can add something to describe the actual invalid value if that would be useful.

Comment: I was missing the `'Identity` attribute~

Answer (score 3):

First, you can define a [sub]type

```
[sub]type Valid_Range_For_X is [Integer] range 23 .. 2001;
```

This will catch most invalid values automatically. If you're using Ada 12, you can add

```
[sub]type Valid_Range_For_X is [Integer] range 23 .. 2001 with
   Dynamic_Predicate => Valid_Range_For_X /= 42;
```

which will catch the internal invalid value as well. It's usually better to let the language do such checks for you than to do them manually.

If you're using an earlier version of Ada, then you'll have to manually check for the internal value. I usually prefer fine-grained exceptions to a general exception used for many things, differentiated by the exception message. So I would raise something like

```
X_Is_42
```

rather than

```
Invalid_Argument with "X is 42"
```

This makes it easier to distinguish the 42 case from the (often many) other kinds of invalid arguments. I realize not everyone agrees with this.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing (we do not have Ada 12). However, my question was not how to define a limited subtype, but dealt with how to create customized exception messages. Perhaps my interpretation of this should be that it is correct to do this, rather than to create custom exception messages?

Comment: I recommend using a fine-grained exception rather than a general exception distinguished by different exception messages. Consider the difference between handling 10 different exceptions to handling a single exception with 10 different messages. Consider the constraints the latter puts on the structure of your code.